# Load Bitmap Image into WINApi C++ and Display

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, bitmap

I am building a GUI using WINApi C++ Unicode. My ultimate goal is not to load the .bmp image from a file because i will be passing around the GUI as a `.exe` file.

Is it possible to load the `.bmp` image into the GUI's resource and load the image from there every time I want to display on my GUI?

Comment: looks like what you need: http://www.jelovic.com/articles/resources_in_visual_studio.htm

Comment: this is .NET. im using C++. Any other advise @AndyT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the resource (`.rc`) file

```
IDI_NORMAL    BITMAP    "Normal.bmp"
```

Then this in main colde (`.cpp`) file

```
HBITMAP hBMP = (HBITMAP)LoadBitmapW(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDI_NORMAL)); //test bitmap

HDC hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
::SelectObject(hMemDC, hBMP);
BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, hMemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
::DeleteDC(hMemDC);
```

Works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Sure. There's a resource type specially for bitmaps. Just use "Add resource" in the Visual Studio resource view. Example code on how to use it should be available in the MSDN.